# preload sound in internet explorer createjs-preloadjs not working

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, createjs, preloadjs

i have to load more than 100 sound files.
its working fine in Mozilla , chrome and safari but not working in internet explorer.

more than 60 sounds also not loading perfectly in internet explorer

what is the maximum sound files we can load at a time?

Answer (score 1):

I have answered your question on GitHub
https://github.com/CreateJS/PreloadJS/issues/216

TLDR: IE maxes out around 41. Edge fixes this with Web Audio support. Consider [Audio sprites](http://createjs.com/docs/soundjs/classes/AudioSprite.html) to combine sounds if need that many sounds in IE.